# View height and width 0 when set with layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Trying to inflate and add a custom view with a specific width and height from a parent view. I have tried using layout params, manually setting the SurfaceView size and much more with no luck. Been stuck on this for a while any help is appreciated.

The height and width of the parent view is correct:

[image]

I have tried inflating the view with an XML layout and calling it programmatically. I'm guessing it has to do something with the parent. The parent was a RelativeLayout view, I have also tried a Frame and Coordinator view. If the parent is the full screen size does that mean the child has no room? How would I solve that, to have multiple views stack of the same size?

```
if (mainVideoView == null) {
        mainVideoView = new VideoView(themedReactContext);
        addView(mainVideoView, new LayoutParams(getWidth(), getHeight()));

        addOnTapListener(mainVideoView);
    }
```

Looking at the layout inspector I can see the layout height and width are set however the actual view height and width is not.

[image]

```
 public void init() {
    createAudioTrack();

    if (mode != null && role != null) {
        if (role.equals(ROLE_PRESENTER)) {
            switch (mode) {
                case MODE_VIDEO:
                    addOnTapListener(mainVideoView);
                    createVideoTrack(null);
                    break;
                case MODE_AR:
                    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.ar_layout, this);
                    arView = findViewById(R.id.ar_container);
                    arView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                    arView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(getWidth(), getHeight(), Gravity.CENTER));
                    arView.setMinimumWidth(getWidth());
                    arView.setMinimumHeight(getHeight());
                    arView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                            getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

                    arView.requestLayout();
                    requestLayout();

                    createVideoTrack(new ViewCapturer(arView.arFragment.getArSceneView()));
                    break;
                case MODE_MEASURE:
                    createVideoTrack(null);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logs of ViewGroup "TwilioVideo" showing the correct size:

```
 I/@@@TwilioVideo: resume
 I/@@@TwilioVideo: twilio video focus: true
 I/@@@TwilioVideo: visibiity: 6
 I/@@@TwilioVideo: AR PRESENTER
 I/@@@TwilioVideo: 2220 1080
 I/@@@ARView: onFinishInflate
 I/@@@Format:  0 0 30
 I/@@@Format:  0 0 30
 I/@@@Format:  0 0 30
 I/@@@Format:  0 0 30
```

Comment: What should the width and height be relative to the parent?

Comment: It should be the same size as the parent. Which is the full screen size of the device.

Comment: Where is this code being called?  If called before the view is measured (like in a constructor) getWidth and getHeight would return 0.  If you want things to work correctly, you need to do this in onMeasure.  Or better yet-  use MATCH_PARENT instead of using the parent's height and width and you don't have to worry about it

Comment: The height and width are not 0 and do get the correct view dimensions. I have a log before the statement. I have tried using MATCH_PARENT with the same effect. Just the layout params changed. Not a change in view size.

Comment: DId you request a layout afterwards?  Changing the layout parameters doesn't force a redraw-  you need to requestLayout for that.  That request to relayout the UI will then relayout the entire screen based on the current information, which will have the change

Comment: I did infact try invalidating, forcing and requesting layout with no success. Im thinking has something to do with the parent physically taking all the space. I want it just as a container to have a stack of fullscreen views within.

Comment: Updated question showing a few things I have tried.